# mac, these keys stops working : "[", "]", "=", "{", "}", "+"

Tags: macos, mac, macos-bigsur, mac-pro

can you please help me figure out why these key are no longer working "[", "]", "=", "{", "}", "+"

I have a MacBook Pro (Retina, 13 inch, late 2013 )

with OS : macOS Big Sur

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

1. Test in Safe Boot [Shift key at boot]
2. Test in another account
3. Test the on-screen keyboard works. [Keyboard prefs to add to menu bar]
4. Try an external keyboard

If 1 & 2 are unsuccessful but 3 & 4 are OK, assume liquid or physical keyboard damage.
If 1 & 2 are successful, then you have a key-command conflict somewhere, which might be harder to figure out.